# How to align the bottom of yet invisible item at the bottom in the recyclerview?

Tags: android

What I want is to align the bottom of item( yet invisible, have never reached) at the bottom of the recycler view. I know the position the item in the recycler view. I tried

```
int position = adapter.indexOf(A.class);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

but it doesn't work properly because it's before onBindViewHolder called so it seems like recyclerview never know the actual height of the item. ( The item has long text and it's set in onBindViewHolder)

1. How can I align the bottom of the item to the bottom of the recycler view?
2. Is it possible I know the item's height before onBindViewHolder ?

Comment: You want to just go to the bottom of your scroll view, right?

Comment: Yes. But under one condition. At the bottom of item has it's own view type.

Comment: scrolling does not matter the type of the view